# Cannot access linker options in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a simple C# WPF application (executable) and I cannot seem to get into the linker options. I copied a screenshot from the internet:

[image]

I want to see this window in my application but I can't find it anywhere. I know I have been in this kind of window before, I forgot how I got there and I've spend an hour now to find it and I'm going nuts. I read everywhere that I have to select my project (not solution) and then go to properties. However, it takes me here:

[image]

Can anybody explain to me in extreme detail how I get to the linker properties? I use Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up C++ annd C#. 
Your first screenshot shows a C++ project, and your second screenshot shows a C# project.
C# doesn't let you manually configure linker options.

Comment: Thanks, I guess you're right, I just created a new C++ project and then the window is available.... Pffff. Well then I guess the help files are incorrect and I have to search again how to make my app force to run as administrator. Thanks for your help!